# When will the Outlook Task API be moved from Beta into V1

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, beta, outlook-api

Hi I want to use the Microsoft Graph - Outlook Task API in a production site - however its been in Beta for 2 years and the last update I found was it would be in the next release  (this was dated 2017). Any news or updates about when this will be available to use.

Answer (score 0):

Chad here from the Tasks team. Yep, it's been a while and we're working on it. I don't have anything we can announce at this point, but we'll let you know when it's ready.